# Определение когда было установлено приложение

Tags: java, android, kotlin

я получаю список всех установленных на телефоне приложения с помощью строки
 `val packageList  = context?.getPackageManager()?.getInstalledPackages(0)`, чтобы потом использовать эот список для отслеживания изменений в системе, однако размер этого списка больше 100, подскажите пожалуйста есть ли какой-то способ определить какие приложения были установлены сразу, а какие установил сам пользователь?

Comment: Вроде бы можно смотреть по пакету приложения, установившего это приложение

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809438/how-to-know-an-application-is-installed-from-google-play-or-side-load

Comment: @Style-7 Нет, вы не поняли, мне нужно следить не за своим приложением, а отделить системные приложения и те которые стояли на телефоне по дефолту от тех которые пользователь устанавливал сам за всё время

Comment: @ДанилСычев Тогда это вы не поняли, что вам послали

Comment: @Style-7  Точно, невнимательно прочитал, спасибо!